# Cold War/WWII movie where American troops sneak into German/Russian party

Tags: identify-this-movie

I watched this 15-20 years ago on PBS (USA), but it looked like it might've been from the late 80's, early 90's. A group of American soldiers have a camp in the woods or a jungle and I think it's towards the end of whatever conflict is going on and there's not much to do.

Things I remember:

- Everyone is outside washing up at a long basin. They complain that they have no hot water, and maybe get scolded for speaking up.
- The squad consists of ~15 guys
- Towards the end of the movie they decide to crash a fancy party being thrown by the enemy (to get some plans or something I think) at a big mansion
- The Americans have one guy with dark hair who can speak the enemy's language. At the party he and a senior officer are approached by one or two attendees. After they exchange awkward words with the enemy he admits to his CO that he's not as fluent as he thought and that he didn't understand most or all of what they said. I can't remember if it was German or Russian, but definitely one or the other.
- I believe they steal/destroy whatever it was they were looking for

Comment: This sounds a bit like Where Eagles Dare, but that film is from the late 60s: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_Eagles_Dare

Comment: Nope. That's not it.

Answer (score 3):

This is [***The Dirty Dozen***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061578/) (1967)

> With the aid of Sergeant Bowren (Richard Jaeckel), the men are taken to a heavily guarded remote camp for training. Nonconformists by nature, Reisman must resort to harsh discipline and incentives to motivate the uncooperative group. When Reisman **deprives them of warm water for shaving**, Bowren labels them, "the Dirty Dozen". As time passes, they finally begin to learn how to work together as a group.

---

> The night of the raid, the men are flown to France, and practice a rhyme they have learned which details their roles in the operation. A slight snag occurs, when upon landing in a tree, one of the dozen, Jiminez (Trini Lopez), breaks his neck and dies, but as trained, the others proceed with the mission, Gilpin taking on Jiminez's duties. Wladislaw and Reisman **infiltrate the meeting disguised as German officer**, while Jefferson and Maggott sneak onto the top floor of the building. **The others set up in various locations around the chateau.**

Comment: I believe this is it! I recognize the dark-haired man's face!